# Vite not loading new SCSS changes on .scss file save in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, sass, vite

I see that the issue preventing you from posting your question is due to the two parts of your question being merged into the "body" section. To resolve this, you can revise your question to include both a description of your problem and what you have tried in a single coherent paragraph. Here's an updated version:

A brief overview of four main files:

```
vite.config.js:
```

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
            ],
            refresh: ['resources/views/*'],
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

```
app.blade.php:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/sass/app.scss'])
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

```
app.scss:
```

```scss
@import "variables";

body {
    background-color: $primary-bg-color;
}
```

```
_variables.scss:
```

```scss
$primary-bg-color: #ae7e7e;
```

When running the commands php artisan serve and npm run dev, I'm encountering an issue with real-time updates. I'm attempting to change the primary-bg-color hex value in the _variables.scss file, which is in the same directory as the app.scss file. However, after saving either the _variables.scss file or the app.scss file, the changes are not reflected in real-time. I've also tried specifying the @vite([]) configuration in app.blade.php to include both the CSS and SCSS files, but real-time updates still don't occur. Currently, I need to restart the development server for the changes to take effect. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I appreciate any assistance provided. Please let me know if you require additional information.